# gasのline bot に関して　取得したメッセージとある言葉を判定する

Tags: google-apps-script

今Line bot を作りたくてgasを用いて精査こうしているのですが、line から取得したdataと'mon'という文字が等しいときにメッセージを送るようにしたいのですが判定の方法で詰まってしまっています。どういう形式で判定したらよいのでしょう
[編集]
 if("mon"==userMessage.text)....①
の部分のプログラムでLINEから取得したメッセージが「mon」というワードと一致したら実行するというプログラムを書いているつもりなのですがうまく作動しませんでした。
①の部分を詳しく教えていただきたいです。

```
function doPost(e) {
  var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents); // LINE から来た json データを JavaScript のオブジェクトに変換する
  var events = data.events;
  for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    var event = events[i];
    var userMessage = events.message.text;
    if(event.type == message){
      if(event.message.type == 'text'){ // 受信したのが普通のテキストメッセージだったとき
        if("mon"==userMessage.text){
          // 送信するデータをオブジェクトとして作成する
          var sheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

          var range=sheet.getRange("B2:B8");
          var cell=range.getCell(5,1).getValue();
          var contents = {
            replyToken: event.replyToken,
            messages: [{ type: 'text', text: cell }],
          };
          reply(contents); // 下で説明
        }
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: 「判定の方法で詰まってしまっています」というのは具体的に何にお困りなのでしょうか。今の書き方だとエラーが出るのか、期待したように動かないのか（そのときはどう操作したらどのように動いてしまうのか）、などなどの情報を書いて、ここからどうしたいのかをもう少し詳細にして頂けると回答しやすいです<(\_ \_)>

Comment: [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)か[indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)を使ってみるとか？ あるいは大文字小文字や全角半角が混在していたり違っていたりするとか？ [JavaScript 文字列を含むかどうかの判定【contains/includes/部分一致の検索】](https://marycore.jp/prog/js/includes-method-contains-method/)

Comment: userMessageは送られてきたテキストの内容になっていますか？